# MVC Two Html.Action in one View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am using MVC 5 and I encountered a problem recently:

I have one Controller [HomeController] and one View with 2 Partials Partial1 and Partial2. 
I tried to render the two partials by using the Html.Action command (because I want the corresponding action to be called).

All the Actions are in the HomeController.

The code works well when being on the localhost and on the development environmet (Visual Studio 2015). 
When I publish the project on Azure I get the following error when trying to execute the View:

```
A single instance of controller 'HomeController' cannot be used to handle
multiple requests. If a custom controller factory is in use, make sure that
it creates a new instance of the controller for each request.
```

I tried to use [ChildActionOnly] with return PartialViewResult on the "partial" actions but with no luck.

I know I can use RenderPartial, but, as i want to make database calls to initialize the Partials, I need to use Html.Action.

Any ideas on the problem?

Code

```
public ActionResult ParentView()
{
    return View();
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult _ChildView1()
{
   WebApi Client3 = new WebApi();

   Guid currentId = Guid.Empty;
   if (Session["CurrentId"] != null)
   {
        currentId = (Guid)Session["CurrentId"];
   }

   ResponseList retModel = Client3 .GetThingsFromDB(currentId);

   return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Folder/_View1.cshtml", retModel);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult _ChildView2()
{
   WebApi Client3 = new WebApi();

   Guid currentId = Guid.Empty;
   if (Session["CurrentId"] != null)
   {
        currentId = (Guid)Session["CurrentId"];
   }

   ResponseList retModel = Client3.GetThingsFromDB(currentId);

   return PartialView("~/Views/Home/Folder/_View2.cshtml", retModel);
}
```

View

```
<div class="seperator">
@{
    Html.RenderAction("_ChildView1","Home");
}
</div>

<div class="seperator">
@{
    Html.RenderAction("_ChildView2","Home");                            
}
</div>
```

The WebApi is a proxy class to a Rest WebApi (different project) that uses IoC (StructureMap) and the calls to the WebApi are made using RestSharp.

I added an empty constructor on the Controller. As I can see the constructor is called only once. Shouldn't it be called 3 times? (one for the parent view and one for each of the two RenderActions?)

StartUp
The HomeController derives only from the Controller class (no base for this controller)

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Owin.Security.Providers.Instagram;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Configuration;

    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]
    namespace WebPortal
    {
        public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Authorize/Login")
            });


            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            var fbOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Provider = new YoohBridgeFacebookAuthenticationProvider(),
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook.clientid"].ToString(),
                AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook.clientsecret"].ToString(),
                BackchannelHttpHandler = new FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
                UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,location"
            };



            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fbOptions);

            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["google.clientid"].ToString(),
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["google.clientsecret"].ToString()
            });



            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;
        }
    }

    public class MyFacebookAuthenticationProvider : FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public MyFacebookAuthenticationProvider() : base() { }

        public override void ApplyRedirect(FacebookApplyRedirectContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri + "&display=popup");
        }
    }

    public class FacebookBackChannelHandler : HttpClientHandler
    {
        protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (!request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/oauth"))
            {
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace("?access_token", "&access_token"));
            }

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Full Trace

```
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.NormalizeLayoutPagePath(String layoutPagePath)
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass21.&lt;BeginInvokeAction&gt;b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.&lt;BeginExecuteCore&gt;b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.&lt;BeginExecute&gt;b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: Post your code - `HomeController`, and all views.

Comment: Do you use a DI (Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control) Container - e.g. Castle Windsor?

Comment: I added some code and more info. thanks

Comment: Is this error coming from your WebAPI project or MVC project?  You mentioned that StructureMap is being used - is this for both MVC and WebAPI, or just WebAPI?  It would be good to see the registrations if this is the case.

Comment: StructureMap is being used only by WebAPI project. The error comes from the MVC, not the WebAPI. And only when it is published on Azure, not on Dev Env.

Comment: Can we get the full stack trace of the error?  And the MVC startup code. Are you using a custom base class for your controllers?  If so, post the code also please.

Comment: The HomeController derives only from the Controller class (no base for this controller)

Comment: For some reason, that I can't Understand, when I run the code locally, the controller gets instantiated 3 times, as it should. But when I publish to Azure, the controller instantiates 1 time and then the error occurs. I completely removed the StructureMap from all solution.

Comment: Do you use custom controller factory?

Comment: Ok, last try, do you possibly use a security mechanism that would cause some kind of, hm, let's call it redirect, from one of the partials back to the home controller when user is not authorized or something?

Comment: No, no such logic. The strange thing is that I only get the problem on Azure, not dev. Could that point somewhere?

Comment: Well, yeah, I guess it points something, but I have got no clue what. I ran out of ideas, I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a looooong research and many tests, as always, the answer was as simple as that:

Clean -> Rebuild (locally)

Publish -> Check "Remove additional files at destination" (to clean the project app on azure)

Thanks a lot for the answers and efford!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are using an IoC (Inversion of Control) pattern and you do instantiate your controllers using an IoC container (Castle Windsor, Autofac, ...). Is that true? If yes, please make sure that the controllers are not registered as singletons - or their lifetime is not "per web request". New controller should be instansiated each time it is required, i.e. its lifetime should be transient (in the Castle Windsor's terminology).